# Xcode Swift: How to make an UIButton create a new object?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

[image: a screenshot of my viewcontroller]

I want my "Add New Notebook" button on the top right to create a new notebook whenever I click on it. And I also want the new notebook to be positioned on the right place. I haven't written any code yet, cuz I have no idea how to even start coding this. I know I have to create an IBAction for the button but I don't know what the next step is.

I'd appreciate it if u guys can help, thanks!

Comment: Put your code here

Comment: What is notebook? Is it view?

Comment: Check this: https://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/build-your-first-app.html

Comment: It might be a good idea for you to get started with some of the basics in creating iOS apps.
Apple got a pretty good tutorial for beginners: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html

Comment: you need a button or a view with action after add new notebook clicked right?

Comment: @keon as per your designs You should use UICollectionView,
first of all just learn the basics of UICollectionView, In the IBAction of your button you should add new data in the array then just reload the collectionView or you can also add the UICollectioViewCell at specific index(in the last index as per your datasource cound).

Comment: @HitendraHckr Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstNotebook: UIView! // Make a ref to the first notebook

@IBAction func addNotebook(_ sender: UIButton) { 
    let newNotebook = UIView(frame: firstNotebook.frame)  // This is making the new notebook using the first ones frame only thing is you would be putting it right over the first one so you need to make a new X position 
    let newX = firstNotebook.frame.origin.x + 40.0 // I have no idea of how far you want it 
    newNotebook.frame.origin.x = newX
    // So you have a new UIView now, you still need to put it in the superView, the superView is already named view for you

    view.addSubview(newNotebook)
}
```

This can get you going but in no way is the right way.  The right way would be to add constraints to make this adaptive but it's a start for you Good Luck!